# Find results between 2 given dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to get results from a SQL date query but I find 0 result

How to format the dates or is it a syntax problem ?

```
Table1
! START_DATE_TIME     ! Result !
!---------------------!--------!
! 2011-03-17 15:09:07 ! name1  !
! 2011-03-18 07:05:15 ! name1  !
! 2011-03-19 14:00:02 ! name2  !
!------------------------------!

date1=as.Date("2011-03-16")
date2=as.Date("2011-03-18")

SELECT * FROM Table1 where START_DATE_TIME 
between date1 and date2
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you attempting to set date parameter in MySQL? or are you passing the query into MySQL? If from outside MySQL what are you using for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the proper way to declare variables. Here it is:

```
SET @var_name = expr;
```

Your query will be this:

```
SET @date1 = '2011-03-16';
SET @date2 = '2011-03-18';

SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE START_DATE_TIME BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

You can find more info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

Answer (score 4):

Using `between` for date/time ranges is an anti-pattern. Prefer explicit range conditions instead:

```
WHERE START_DATE_TIME >= '2011-03-16'
  AND START_DATE_TIME < '2011-03-19'
```

Note the inclusive lower bound (`>=`) and exclusive upper bound (`<`) for the first moment that is to be excluded.

Rationale:

- Time units are not uniform (leap years, leap seconds make it hard to calculate the correct last moment of any period)
- The time component’s resolution is unknown (how many .9999 to include?)

You can include the dates themselves (in single quotes) in **ad-hoc queries**. If you are executing the statement form a program, use **bind variables**.

In comparisons, dates (without time component) are automatically extended to timestamps including the 00:00:00 time.

More about this: http://modern-sql.com/feature/extract#anit-patter-where-clause

Comment: Although **very** sound advice, this doesn't actually answer the specific syntax question (on setting parameters)

Comment: @Used_By_Already not sure if the parameters were the actual question. I mentioned that inlining the values is fine for ad-hoc queries, but not for programs.